# Where can I find a searchable text of Mahabharata online?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, vyasa

I want to be able to search across the entire Mahabharata for certain words or phrases. I have seen pages where you have to click to different pages to navigate through. But I want to be able to search across the entire text at once. Is there any such resource available?

Comment: get an epub book.